# How to replace left_column with center_column just on mobile in Prestashop-1.6

Tags: php, themes, prestashop-1.6

I'd like to replace left_column with center_column just on mobile. It works well on tablet and laptop.

As you can see in attachment I have tried to replace left_column -which is marked with red rectangle- with center_column -which is marked with blue rectangle- just on mobile device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAnLU.png

{if isset($left_column_size) && !empty($left_column_size)}
                        {$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}
                        {/if}
                        {if isset($left_column_size) && isset($right_column_size)}{assign var='cols' value=(12 - $left_column_size - $right_column_size)}{else}{assign var='cols' value=12}{/if}
                        
                        {/if}